# Installing EntityFramework to solution with multiple projects

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a solution with 4 projects.
    1. View, 2. ViewModel, 3. Model, 4. DataAccess

Is it necessary to install EntityFramework in all the projects? if not which project will be most suitable to install it.?

And which project should be referenced to which project?

' #WPF, #MVVM, #EF-CodeFirst #EntityFramework

Comment: #DataAccess https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/orm-9780596520281-01-20.aspx

Comment: @lawst. i installed EF via nuget in DataAccess and ViewModel project.   From DataAccess project added reference to model project. From ViewModel project added reference to all other 3 projects.

Answer (score 0):

You should install EF in your **Model** project and **DataAccess** project.
**DataAccess** project will be referenced to **Model** project and **ViewModel** project.
**View** project will be referenced to **ViewModel** project.

Comment: Assuming Model is the entity models, why would you add EF there? DataAccess would have EF and reference Model project, no?

Comment: I suppose that Model project contains also entity data model and MyDBContext class. MyDBContext class represents the Entity Framework "My" database context and derives from the DbContext base class. In order to be able to reference DbContext and DbSet, we need to install EF in our Model project.
Yes, DataAccess must have EF. I have corrected my answer. Thanks.